# Did the practice of polygamy in ancient India have the effect of preventing other men from getting married?

Tags: practice, women, marriage

In contemporary India, due to the practice of female infanticide over several generations, the male to female gender ratio [has been heavily skewed](https://www.cnn.com/2018/01/30/health/india-unwanted-girls-intl/index.html), and the [country has more men than women](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_and_union_territories_of_India_by_sex_ratio). As a result, many men complain that they can't find a wife.

> The male-skew in India's sex ratio has increased significantly since the early 20th century. In 1901 there were 3.2 million fewer women than men in India, but by the 2001 Census the disparity had increased by more than a factor of 10, to 35 million.This increase has been variously attributed to female infanticide, selective abortions (aided by increasing access to prenatal sex discernment procedures), and female child neglect. It has been suggested that the motivation for this selection against female children is due to the lower status and perceived usefulness of women in India's patriarchal society.

Similarly, the practice of polygamy has the effect of creating more lifelong celibate males, since the pool of single women for marriage is reduced.

On the other hand, polygamy is useful when there is a gender imbalance in which women outnumber men, and polyandry is forbidden in Hinduism.

Does any Hindu scripture talk about the sociological ill-effects of polygamy?

Comment: "polyandry is forbidden in Hinduism." Actually, no, polyandry is normal in hinduism e.g. Draupadi married 5 Pandava's.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu That is the exception because of a boon she received. It is a huge sin for women to have multiple partners in Hinduism.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, nope, it is not Normal. After living with one brother, Draupadi would bathe in fire (agni-pravesh) and regain her virginity, before living with another brother. if today's women are willing to do the same ritual, they can. If you're going to ask me 'where did you hear that ? that seems highly impossible/fiction-like. show me evidence', then let me direct you to my next comment.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, have you seen Draupadi ? Who is he / she ? Where did you hear about her ? Did you gather enough evidence yourself to check if she is a real person or imaginary fiction like Pixie fairy ? Or did you just hear about her in some popular mythological ancient story and blindly believed her to be real? taking something on faith would be rather unscientific, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @ram exactly my point. There is lack of proof therefore one should assume it is mythological.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, exactly my point. Since you consider Mahabharata and hence Draupadi to by mythological since you don't have proof, you should also consider 'her having 5 husbands' to be mythological since you don't have proof. If Draupadi never existed how can you believe 'she had 5 husbands' ?

Comment: @ram I look at it from the scriptures/dharma point of view. It is as easy as that.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu, i don't understand your point at all. Where did you hear about Draupadi ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90546/discussion-between-wikash-hindu-and-ram).

Comment: "practice of polygamy has the effect of creating more lifelong celibate males" - actually, it's the other way round. the practice of lifelong celibacy has the effect of creating polygamous households.

Comment: @ram Yes, but it depends which was one was more common. Most people in ancient times were Grihasthas.

Comment: polygamy would not have had any effect on sex ratio because there were also many men who remained brahmachari-monk by choice for their whole life without marrying